# React Native 360/Panorama viewer

Tags: react-native, opengl, google-vr, panoramas

I believe there are a bunch of questions related to this, but they are all outdated.

I'm looking for a way to render a panorama/360 picture viewer in React Native. So far, all the libraries that try to use Google's VR SDK are outdated or broken, and not usable at all.

I have also tried to use a WebView (with react-360), but web views are just way too slow, doubles RAM usage, and worst of all, can't be used to render 360 pictures stored on the device.

I guess that another option would be to grab an OpenGL library and try to implement it myself, but that's probably a lot of work if there's something made already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've recently published the panorama viewer we are using in our apps. Hope it can help you too. [@lightbase/react-native-panorama-view](https://github.com/lightbasenl/react-native-panorama-view)

Comment: It did help! Not fully, but a few updates here and there made it perfect!

Comment: Is it compatible with expo apps?

Comment: I do see that there haven't been any releases since 2021. Is this still being actively developed?